# how to view Docx file in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, dart-null-safety

I get all docx files now i want to open the file using file path can someone help. I tried power file view, flutter file view etc packages but all engines failed to load can someone provide material to open Docx file in flutter.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [Docx template engine for flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/docx_template), you can also check youtube where this package is used in flutter tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin to open docx files in your flutter app

https://pub.dev/packages/open_file

Example:-

```
OpenFile.open("/sdcard/example.docx");//add your file path here
```